# How to mock an API that returns a file

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a function `(api_upload)` that accepts a file and HTTP headers, it then sends the file along with the HTTP headers to an API service `(example.com/upload)`, which processes the file, and returns a URL of the processed file.

I am trying to write a unit test for this function `(api_upload)`, and I am feeling a bit lost since this is my first time playing with unit-tests. I have installed `pip install requests-mock` and also `pip install pytest-mock`. I guess my question is how do I mock the `example.com/upload`, because I don't need to actually call `example.com/upload` in my testing. But I need to test that the function `api_upload` is "working" as expected.

```
def api_upload(input_file, headers):

    # covert the input_file into a dictionary, since requests library wants a dictionary 
    input_file = {'file': input_file}

    url = 'https://example.com/upload'

    files = {'file': open(input_file['file'], 'rb')}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

    saved_file_url = response.json()['url']
    return saved_file_url
```

What I tried is:

```
def test_api_upload(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.get("https://example.com/upload", text='What do I put here?')
    #I am not sure what else to write here?
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to alter is the (HTTP) method you call. `api_upload()` does a `POST` request so that needs to be matched by `requests_mock` call.

The second thing is that you need to mock the response that the mock would return for your `requests.post()` call. `api_upload()` apparently expects JSON that consists of an object with `url` as one of the attributes. That's what you need to return then.

As to what you should do inside your test function, I'd say:

1. Mock the `POST` call and the expected response.
2. Call `api_upload()` and give it a mock file (see [`tmp_path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html#the-tmp-path-fixture) that returns an instance of `pathlib.Path`).
3. Assert that the returned URL is what you mocked.

An untested example:

```py
def test_api_upload(requests_mock, tmp_path):
    file = tmp_path / "a.txt"
    file.write_text("aaa")
    mocked_response = {"url": "https://example.com/file/123456789"}   
    requests_mock.post("https://example.com/upload", json=mocked_response)
    
    assert api_upload(input_file=str(file), headers={}) == mocked_response["url"]
```